# In Wordpress, wp_query with special attribute

Tags: wordpress

When I use the WP_Query, I want to filter them by titles' initial letter, Like I only want the post when the initial is between 'F-J', what should I do with it.

```
$query_arguments = array(
        'post_type' => $atts['_type'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => $atts['postsPerPage'],
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    $trombinoscope_query = new WP_Query($query_arguments);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a meta_key, it's fine for me now.
like this

```
function set_meta_for_employe_post() {
    $post_title = get_the_title();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    if ('employe' == get_post_type()) {
        if($post_title) {
                add_post_meta($post_id, 'initial_letter', $post_title[0], true);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_meta_for_employe_post');
```

and after:

```
$query_arguments = array(
        'post_type' => $atts['_type'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => $atts['postsPerPage'],
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_key' => 'initial_letter',
        'meta_value' => $letters,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the mysql solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712272/wp-query-to-show-pages-that-starts-with-some-character).

Something as :

```
<?php
    $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE (post_title like 'F%' OR post_title like 'G%' OR post_title like 'I%' OR post_title like 'F%') AND post_status='publish'"); 
    if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); 

        //Your code comes here.

    endforeach; endif;
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but I have already done this. I add a meta to post, for initial letter, after I use the meta_key with meta_value, it's fine now.

Comment: @WeiweiHan I'm happy that you've found out, and sorry for my respond which haven't worked, I've just picked it on the link and change it a tiny bit.